# actionscript-3: refactor interface inheritance to get rid of ambiguous reference error

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, oop

imagine there are two interfaces arranged via composite pattern, one of them has a `dispose` method among other methods:

```
interface IComponent extends ILeaf {
    ...
    function dispose() : void;
}

interface ILeaf {
    ...
}
```

some implementations have some more things in common (say an `id`) so there are two more interfaces:

```
interface ICommonLeaf extends ILeaf {
    function get id() : String;
}

interface ICommonComponent extends ICommonLeaf, IComponent {
}
```

so far so good. but there is another interface which also has a `dispose` method:

```
interface ISomething {
    ...
    function dispose() : void;
}
```

and `ISomething` is inherited by ICommonLeaf:

```
interface ICommonLeaf extends ILeaf, ISomething {
    function get id() : String;
}
```

As soon as the `dispose` method is invoked on an instance which implements the `ICommonComponent` interface, the compiler fails with an ambiguous reference error because `ISomething` has a method called `dispose` and `ILeaf` also has a `dispose` method, both living in different interfaces (`IComponent, ISomething`) within the inheritace tree of ICommonComponent.

I wonder how to deal with the situation if

- the `IComponent`, the `ILeaf` and the `ISomething` can't change.
- the composite structure must also work for for the `ICommonLeaf` & `ICommonComponent`
- implementations and the `ICommonLeaf` & `ICommonComponent` must conform to the `ISomething` type.

this might be an actionscript-3 specific issue. i haven't tested how other languages (for instance java) handle stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for a solution to the Diamond Problem. C# has an approach to this but basically I would factor the method "dispose" out of your interfaces and create a new "IDisposable".

If the same name like "id" is used twice, it looks like a problem in your code with an ambiguous name. We started to add prefixes to properties and methods. Imagine you have a property "name" that belongs to two different things. Like the "displayName" and the "uniqueName".

This also helps with auto completion. If a DisplayObject is an ILayoutObject and yout type `displayObject.layout` you get everything layout releated.

Comment: yes, an IDisposable interface would certainly solve the issue, but unfortunately I don't have access to the IComponent and ISomething interfaces to extract dispose.

Answer (score 1):

It seems casting solves the ambiguity even though it's far from neat.

```
class SomeComponent implements ICommonComponent {}

var c : ICommonComponent = new SomeComponent();
trace(ISomething(c).dispose()); //compiles
trace(IComponent(c).dispose()); //compiles
trace(c.dispose());    //fails
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's no neat way to deal with this problem in Actionscript.

The only thing I can think of is refactoring your interfaces to avoid name clashes, which, admitedly, it's not always possible.

Don't know about Java, but C# has a way to handle this through [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx).